# Mysql Join Query taking a long time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query which is taking a long time to execute.
Table descriptions. These tables are very large so will give relevant columns in description. All Columns are varchar.

> Table 1 - General
>    PK - CLAIM_ID
>   No of Records - 2.63  Mill,
>
> Table 2 - Enrol
>   No of Records - 2.5 Million
>   Cols - CLAIM_ID(PK),POLICY_ID,MEMBER_ID
>
> Table 3 - Member
>   No fo Records - 28 million
>   Cols - MEMBER_ID(PK),POLICY_GROUP_ID
>
> Table 4 - Policy
>   No fo Records - 2 Million
>   Cols- POLICY_ID,policy_sub_general_type_id
>
> table 5 - Balance
>   No of Records - 12 Million.
>   Columns

Query is

```
SELECT  cg.CLAIM_ID,mem.Policy_group_ID ,
CAST(CASE when pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PFL'
               then (bal2.sum_insured - bal2.utilised_sum_insured)
          when pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PNF'
               then (bal1.sum_insured - bal1.utilised_sum_insured)
     end AS DECIMAL(10, 2) ) Balance_SI
    FROM  General cg
    LEFT JOIN  Enrol ce  ON cg.CLAIM_ID = ce.CLAIM_ID
    LEFT JOIN  Member mem  ON ce.MEMBER_ID = mem.MEMBER_ID
    LEFT JOIN  Policy pol  ON pol.POLICY_ID = ce.POLICY_ID
    LEFT join  Balance bal1  ON bal1.MEMBER_ID = ce.MEMBER_ID
                           and  bal1.MEMBER_ID is not null
    LEFT join  Balance bal2  ON bal2.Policy_group_ID = mem.Policy_group_ID
                           and  bal2.Policy_group_ID is not null
    GROUP BY  cg.CLAIM_ID
```

Explain Statement shows

```
Select Type|table|Type|key|rows|Extra
_____________________________________
SIMPLE|cg |index|PRIMARY|2662233|Using Index
SIMPLE|ce |ref|index1|1|NULL
SIMPLE|mem|eq_ref|PRIMARY|1|using where
SIMPLE|pol|eq_ref|PRIMARY|1| Using Where
SIMPLE|bal1|ref|index2|3|Using Where
SIMPLE|bal2|ref|index1|1|using where
```

Server params

> InnoDB_Buffer_pool - 10GB
>   InnoDB_Log_File_Size - 3GB
>   4 Core processor

All tables and columns have same collation and character set, So this is not a collation issue. Also also join columns are varchar. Explain  statement shows ( I assume) tables are indexed well.
Query takes around 15 minutes to return first 50000 rows which is unacceptable at this point of time.For entire table it is still running for last 3 hours without any result. 
No Idea why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: I have very bad experience indexing and joining on varchar data type. I join using integer id(s) and if required match varchar id(s) from both the tables in WHERE part

Comment: Without SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, it's really impossible to help.

Comment: Do you really need a result with 2662233 rows ?

Comment: @Vatev Yes..Unfortunately I do

Comment: @Strawberry Ok I will add the show create statements as well

Comment: Also, as Vatev has observed, it does seem decidedly unfortunate that you want all rows returned, regardless of whether they satisfy the joining criteria.

Comment: Like @Strawberry pointed out, we need more info to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: @AngryLeo can you run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` from the same tables (and same joins) w/o the group by? If that happens to take too long, remove the `ref` type joins 1 by 1 until it completes. The idea is to find out which joins add a large number of rows to the temp result set (before group by).

Comment: Also, there are no aggregating functions here. While GROUP BY is (depressingly) more performant than DISTINCT, it's liable to return misleading results - unless you're very, very careful.

Comment: You are aggregating by one column but selecting many others, with no aggregation functions.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: As Gordon just mentioned - please explain why do you need `GROUP BY`? I have a feeling that you want at least `SUM` against your `CAST` field. Please post all tables involved schemas - that will bring us some idea about your DB and app design.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry guys. Added more explanation about the tables and the purpose of the query.Please see if it is more helpful now

Comment: It was a straightforward request :-(.   See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you change all the `LEFT JOINs` to `JOINs` and get rid of the `IS NOT NULL` tests, do you get the same (correct) answer?

Comment: Even the numeric values are `VARCHARs`??

Comment: What the heck will you do with 2.6M rows of output?  Maybe you can do some more processing in the `SELECT`?

Comment: @AngryLeo - No, we need `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We can't see the exact datatypes, the indexes, and other things.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can completely remove your "cg" alias General table unless you are using for some other columns you are not showing here.  Reason, you have the claim ID directly from your enrollment table.  Just removes extra level.

Next, your Group by is only on the claim, but the policy group ID is part of your select.  Did you intend to have it aggregated per policy too?  Can one claim be covered by multiple policy groups?  If not and you are just trying to carry that forward, you can keep it via 
    MAX( mem.Policy_Group_ID ) as Policy_Group_ID

As noted by Strawberry, doing aggregates / group by where you MIGHT have Cartesian results could give you false answers.

I would also suggest editing your post and confirming some additional details such as the Balance Table.  You have one total based on "PFL" for "PNF" we know there specific meaning behind them, but mean nothing to us.  Your case/when is pulling the value from the "Bal1" vs "Bal2" alias why.  Is this a condition where a specific policy group is NOT entered into the balance table and it falls into either some "generic bucket", or a bucket specific to a single policy?  Such as regular coverage of "X", but you have a limit on category "Y"?

Below is cleaner SQL readability with removal of the general table.

```
SELECT  
      ce.CLAIM_ID,
      mem.Policy_group_ID,
      CAST(CASE when pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PFL' 
                   then (bal2.sum_insured - bal2.utilised_sum_insured)
                when pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PNF' 
                   then (bal1.sum_insured - bal1.utilised_sum_insured) end AS DECIMAL(10,2)) Balance_SI
   FROM 
      Enrol ce
         LEFT JOIN Member mem
            on ce.MEMBER_ID = mem.MEMBER_ID
         LEFT join Balance bal2
            on mem.Policy_group_ID = bal2.Policy_group_ID
            and bal2.Policy_group_ID  <> ''
         LEFT JOIN Policy pol
            on ce.POLICY_ID = pol.POLICY_ID
         LEFT join Balance bal1
            on ce.MEMBER_ID = bal1.MEMBER_ID
            and bal1.MEMBER_ID <> ''
   GROUP BY 
      ce.CLAIM_ID
```

Finally, looking at your case/when and join on Bal2 alias, you have no reference to a member ID, so lets show you the Cartesian Killer you are probably encountering.  Example, Federal employees fall into a policy group and have 20k employees.  Now you have one Enrollment record left-joining to the balance table?  is it one record per policy group or one per member / policy group.  If the per member / policy, you are plowing through 20k balance records every time trying to get value from Bal2.  While the Balance table "Bal1" alias is explicit per member ID.  So I know both fields are in the table and that might be killing you.

Again, please edit your existing post for clarification of details and relationships, especially 1:1 vs 1:n

Comment: Added more explanation about the tables and the purpose of the query.Please see if it is more helpful now

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer yet**

Your DB schema is not clear to me.

I have many questions and a lot of ideas how to speed this query up.

Lets take a look on your 1st part of query:

```
SELECT  cg.CLAIM_ID,
    mem.Policy_group_ID,
    CAST(
      CASE 
        when 
pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PFL' then
(bal2.sum_insured - bal2.utilised_sum_insured)
            when pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PNF' then
(bal1.sum_insured - bal1.utilised_sum_insured)
          END
        AS DECIMAL(10,2)
        ) Balance_SI
```

You have "inline" function calls, which hit the performance: `CAST, CASE, bal1.sum_insured - bal1.utilised_sum_insured, bal2.sum_insured - bal2.utilised_sum_insured`

If your app or whatever you do can accept not "formatted" result to be returned by query, I would suggest to remove `CAST` - it will speed up query a bit with no affect on real values returned. You can round those values later on application level.

Next is `CASE`, again if you have your app level (I hope) you can return raw data instead of transformed result. I mean you can return 3 columns: `pol.policy_sub_general_type_id, bal1.sum_insured - bal1.utilised_sum_insured, bal2.sum_insured - bal2.utilised_sum_insured` instead of `CASE`. But I suspect you don't need even this optimization. I'll show that later.

I have many questions about your `JOIN`s as well. But since you did not reply on DRapp answer yet I will keep my questions for a while.

Lets go directly to the query I suspect will return almost the same data you need and discuss details later if you will have any particular questions.

```
SELECT
    cg.CLAIM_ID,
    mem.Policy_group_ID ,
    SUM(bal.sum_insured - bal.utilised_sum_insured) Balance_SI
FROM `General` cg
LEFT JOIN Enrol ce
ON cg.CLAIM_ID = ce.CLAIM_ID
LEFT JOIN Member mem
ON ce.MEMBER_ID = mem.MEMBER_ID
LEFT JOIN Policy pol
ON pol.POLICY_ID = ce.POLICY_ID
  AND (pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PNF' 
       OR pol.policy_sub_general_type_id = 'PFL')
LEFT JOIN Balance bal
ON (bal.MEMBER_ID = ce.MEMBER_ID
   AND bal.MEMBER_ID <> '')
   OR (bal.Policy_group_ID = mem.Policy_group_ID 
   AND bal.Policy_group_ID  <> '')
GROUP BY cg.CLAIM_ID, mem.Policy_group_ID
```

Comment: Nice offer, but if you looked at the original query, his join to the Balance table was based two separate as you have "OR" applied.  The issue is what are they really trying to aggregate and believe there IS a Cartesian result he is falling into.

Comment: @DRapp lets wait for OP comments, I feel like he does not need 2 joins.

Comment: @Alex Added more explanation about the tables and the purpose of the query.Please see if it is more helpful now

Comment: @AngryLeo did you check my query? Does it return different result than your? What is the difference? Why it is wrong (if it is)?

Comment: `OR` is likely to obliterate any chance to use an index for `JOINing`.